# Parse date from string using a pattern

Tags: bash, date, parsing, pattern-matching

Given the string

```
log-2015-02-10
```

I'd like to parse date from it using some kind of pattern like

```
log-YYYY-mm-dd
```

Is it possible in Bash?

Answer (score 1):

The `date` command can parse strings, but you can't specify a format like you can with the `strptime` library call from a lower-level language.  You could do something like this, though:

```
s=log-2015-02-10
when=$(date -d "${s#log-}")
echo $when # Tue Feb 10 00:00:00 EST 2015
```

Comment: Could I use something similar if the parts of a date will be swapped? I mean, for instance, 'log-10-02-2015'.

Comment: If you need control over how the date is parsed, you'll probably need to do it manually, as in @chepner's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possibilities, but here's a simple one that gives you the three date components in separate variables:

```
IFS=- read _ year month day <<< log-2015-02-10
```

If the input wasn't a simple set of delimited fields, you could use a regular expression (which could be more general than the one show here):

```
[[ log-2015-02-10 =~ log-(....)-(..)-(..) ]]
year=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
month=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
day=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
```